# How to tag keywords and add to new column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, tags, keyword

I'm trying to extract tags founds in sentences with the code below but it returns the keywords instead. What am I missing? How can I output a new column of all tags (instead of keywords) separated by comma?

```
s = set(dict_list)
f = lambda x: ', '.join(set([y for y in x.split() if y in s]))
# df['tags'] = df['description_summary'].apply(f)

df['tags'] = df['description_summary'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x.split()).intersection(s)))
df
```

Here is basically the data I'm working with in an excel file:

```
    description_summary

0   Long sentence with keywords ball and hot
1   Long sentence with keywords stick, glove, and cold
```

Here is the current (wrong) output:

```
     description_summary                                     keywords instead of tags

0    Long sentence with keywords ball and hot                ball, hot
1    Long sentence with keywords cold, stick, and glove      cold, stick, glove
```

Here is the output I want:

```
     description_summary                                     tags

0    Long sentence with keywords ball and hot                toy, temperature
1    Long sentence with keywords cold, stick, and glove      temperature, toy
```

Here is the dictionary of keywords and tags ('keywords': 'tags'):

```
dict_list = {'Hot': 'Temperature',
 'Cold': 'Temperature',
 'Very cold': 'Temperature',
 'Ball': 'Toy',
 'Glove': 'Toy',
 'Stick': 'Toy'
 }
```

How can I output only the tags (separated by comma) in a new column of the same file?

Comment: Why not just continue processing your keywords using your tags dictionary?

Comment: What do you mean? Could you provide an example? Sorry, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal dictionary indexing to return the associated value, rather than the key itself.

Note I've edited the dictionary list from your question to make it easier to verify this works, and that you also need to account for case-sensitivity.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'description_summary':['Long sentence with keywords ball and hot',
                                          'Long sentence with keywords cold, stick, and glove']})

dict_list = {'Hot': 'Temperature (hot)',
             'Cold': 'Temperature (cold)',
             'Very cold': 'Temperature (very cold)',
             'Ball': 'Toy (ball)',
             'Glove': 'Toy (glove)',
             'Stick': 'Toy (stick)'}

d_lower = {key.lower():value.lower() for key, value in dict_list.items()}

df['tags'] = df['description_summary'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(
      set([d_lower[y] for y in d_lower.keys() if y in x])
    ))
```

yields `'tags'`

```
0                   temperature (hot), toy (ball)
1    temperature (cold), toy (glove), toy (stick)
Name: tags, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, Brendan. This works great but it looks like it still misses keywords in some rows but I'm not sure why. Most of the ones missed appear to have a capital first letter. How would I solve this?

Comment: Can't debug code without a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If this 'works great' you might consider accepting the answer.